# What is "4" doing in below code piece?

Tags: c#, console.writeline

I understand `{0}` is the 1st argument as `id`, `{1}` is the second argument as `sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds` but what is `4` for?

```
Console.WriteLine("End counting {0} : {1, 4:N0} ms", id, sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `4` is alignment specifier. It specifies to align the number 4 units right.

> Controlling alignment
>
> By default, strings are right-aligned within their field if you specify a field width. To left-align strings in a field, you preface the field width with a negative sign, such as {0,-12} to define a 12-character right-aligned field.`

From [String.Format Method - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It's the **alignment**. From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting) (emphasis mine):

> Each format item takes the following form and consists of the following components:
>   `{index[,alignment][:formatString]}`
>
> ...
>
> The optional *alignment* component is a signed integer indicating the preferred formatted field width. If the value of *alignment* is less than the length of the formatted string, *alignment* is ignored and the length of the formatted string is used as the field width. **The formatted data in the field is right-aligned if *alignment* is positive and left-aligned if *alignment* is negative.** If padding is necessary, white space is used. The comma is required if *alignment* is specified.